# Alien girl gets sustenance from photosynthesis

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, childrens-novel

This is a short story I read in the 1st grade, some 20+ years ago, that was included in our reading textbook.

What I remember is that the girl in the story was new to the area, possibly a Mars or Moon colony, and she was different than many of the students. For one, I believe she was green. She also spent time in a room with a giant skylight, because she got all of her energy from photosynthesis.

I don't remember if there was any plot besides that. I believe the story was actually used to segue into teaching us about plants, so there's the possibility this was a small excerpt of a larger work.

(It's not *All Summer in a Day*, but a recent question about that story reminded me of this one)

---

If it helps, I'm almost positive the textbook this was in also included the story [*Lose Now, Pay Later*](https://www.quia.com/files/quia/users/christinawade/TextFiles/SciFi/H.O._Lose_Now,_Pay_Later.pdf) by Carol Farley. But, it *was* a grade-school textbook, not an anthology work (so, not *2041*).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was searching for this story too, and knew almost exactly as much as you did—that it was about green photosynthetic kids, and that I associated it with "Lose Now, Pay Later" (a story I went on a similar search for several years ago). I'd forgotten the skylight, but vaguely remembered there being red-skinned kids too.

After an hour of searching, I came across what I'm pretty sure is the right story: "[The Green People of Solaron](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj5jaXVgqXSAhVE34MKHZ9aAV0QFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cwcboe.org%2Fcms%2Flib04%2Fnj01001185%2Fcentricity%2Fdomain%2F218%2Fthe_green_people_of_solaron._article_and_questions.doc&usg=AFQjCNHy6yCR8dQf4UIyNweDCd9yGcQXog&sig2=SZuTmgxWgNSVj-_xq8Pg8A)." I only found a document file and references to it in lesson plans, no author information or independent references to it whatsoever. I even looked through the contents of the textbook I was able to find that had "Lose Now, Pay Later" in it, to no avail. Which makes me wonder if we had the same 7th Grade English class :).

> *Scientists on Earth wanted to know whether human skin cells could act
>   like tiny plants by using the energy of sunlight to make glucose from
>   carbon dioxide and water.  This process called photosynthesis produces
>   glucose, a sugar plants use as food.  If human cells could make their
>   own food, scientists thought, colonists on planets such as Solaron
>   would not have to grow so much food.  With less need for grown food,
>   the colonists on Solaron could have smaller farms.  This would save
>   precious space under the colony’s bubble and conserve limited energy
>   resources.   Green people could help Solaron in another way too. 
>   Oxygen is a byproduct of photosynthesis.  Human photosynthesis would
>   be a source of oxygen.  Green people would give off oxygen – just a
>   green plants do – for other people to breathe.*

Here's an illustration from the textbook this short story appeared in:

[image]

And this is a home like the main character Zara's, which is essentially a giant skylight:

[image]

Comment: This... Seems like it may be the _complete_ story that would have been in the text book, without illustrations. I read this in **1st** grade, but I'm pretty sure it was a textbook designed to be used throughout elementary school. I have to look into this more before accepting, but this is an amazing jumping point and I'll be surprised if not it.

Comment: You may like this: http://sciencewithmrsmorton.weebly.com/uploads/5/8/7/0/58703399/skmbt_65416030408570.pdf

Comment: [This scan is in color, and is for sure the illustrations I remember, but I also know that the "Lose Now, Pay Later" had similar illustrations.](http://www.chsd.us/~mbendele/cells/cells%20book%20copied.pdf) I can't tell if maybe I'm just mixing up the relationship, or if Prentice Hall once published _Lose Now, Pay Later_ as part of another science book and what I read was compendium. Regardless, after finding the illustrations I can confirm this was 100% the right answer.

Comment: Also Tom, welcome to the SF & Fantasy Stack. Great first answer! I hope you'll stick around.