# Old sci-fi book about humans who are part plant and have chlorophyll in their blood

Tags: story-identification, books

My dad was telling me about a book he read as a teen about a group of people who had chlorophyll in their blood and had become part human, part plant.

Sunlight hurt their eyes, so they would make Goggles out of leaves, and if they stood still they could become a part of their surroundings and wouldn't be seen.

My dad is in his 60s now, so it was probably written before 1970, but he couldn’t remember the title or author. I searched online, but couldn’t find anything.

I would greatly appreciate any help identifying this work..

Comment: Can this be the same as the textbook part described in the answer https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/153184/4918 "Alien girl gets sustenance from photosynthesis"?

Comment: For some reason I'm thinking of *Midworld* (ISTR they had to protect their eyes when they went up to the treetops), but I can't recall if the colonists had green skin or just the furcots.

Comment: It's probably only similar- Top Secret
by John Reynolds Gardiner from 1980s is about a boy who turns himself half plant with a science experiment.

Comment: Cat I salute your effort to help your dad.  I procrastinated on a book find request from my father and he died unexpectedly before I did anything.  Good luck with your search

Comment: There's one in _Dangerous Visions_ or its sequel like this.

Comment: I've vague recollection of a novel, where a man wakes up and starts exploring. Its a jungle world. (might be ruins of cities) He discovers where he came from. A cave/ruins of an underground bunker, where a computer is making Clones to populate the world. BUT it has been 10s or 100s of thousands of years. The facility is heavily damaged, and most of the clones produced are contaminated and not viable. (lots of discarded half/miss formed bodies) Eventually it is revealed he is not human, but a human/plant hybrid the system dumped out due to contamination, but he survived.

Comment: If I remember right, he did meet a woman, and there might have been 1 or two other 'people' they meet, who we realize came from the same place. But due to the damage, the facility will never produce a "true human".

Comment: I want to know its title and author, too. I remember the chlorophyll being the result of a virus. And since everyone could make their own energy food was no longer a currency. They had switched to calories.

Answer (score 4):

This story affected me too; I think I saw it in Omni magazine.

"Village of the Chosen" by I think Alan Dean Foster.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Note that story dates from 1983, so it might be too late for the one the OP is thinking of, but you should still add more details to describe how it matches.

Comment: On top of the above note that I’ve removed the link to your website. It would be best to upload the image here directly only. Not all of [this help page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) applies but you might want to give it a read as it gives some tips on what [not] to do with self promotion.

Comment: @DavidW _Omni_ did sometimes reprint old stories.

Comment: @Spencer However the [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?73269) does not show any earlier publication for "Village of the Chosen".